# How to interpret this address -0x80(%rbp,%rax,4)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm currently trying to learn assembly language (and the effects of different compiler options) by analyzing simple C code snippets. Now I stumpled across the following instruction:

```
mov %edx,-0x80(%rbp,%rax,4)
```

What I do not understand is the expression for the target address `-0x80(%rbp,%rax,4)`.
The instruction assigns a value to a local array in a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The machine command will copy the content of `%edx` to the address given by `%rbp + 4 * %rax - 0x80`. It seems `%rax` is holding the index to that array and `%rbp - 0x80` is the base address.

Take a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) to get a better understanding for the AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 9):

```
-0x80(%rbp,%rax,4) = *(%rbp + %rax * 4 + (-0x80))
```

So the following insruction:

```
mov %edx,-0x80(%rbp,%rax,4)
```

means let CPU move the value of register %edx to memory at address `(%rbp + %rax * 4 + (-0x80))`, this is AT&T-style assembly.