# What exactly is this instruction doing?

Tags: x86-64, intel, att

I am having troubles understanding what this instruction is doing:

```
add    0x402780(,%rdx,4),%ecx
```

I've tried running through it with different values to figure out what it is doing, but still no luck.

Comment: `add (32-bit) dword @ mem: [0x402780 + rdx * 4] to: ecx`

Comment: So is it using the value @ 0x402780 or is it using it as an offset/base?

Comment: I'm sure there are a [lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359068/how-to-interpret-this-address-0x80rbp-rax-4?rq=1) of similar AT&T vs Intel questions that provide a more comprehensive answer. That said, it is an 'offset', but since no base is supplied, it is *effectively* a base.